# Can we create temporary pass-in `std::vector<int>` parameter?

Tags: c++

```
void PrintNow(const std::vector<int> &v)
{
    std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;
}

std::vector<int>().push_back(20); // this line generates no complains
PrintNow(std::vector<int>().push_back(20)); // error
```

From VS2010 Sp1:

> eror C2664: 'PrintNow' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void' to
>   'const std::vector<_Ty> &'

Q> Is it possible that we can pass a temporary vector to function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In C++11 you can just do:

```
void PrintNow(const std::vector<int> &v)
{
    std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;
}

PrintNow({20});
```

VS2010 doesn't yet support this part of C++11 though. (gcc 4.4 and clang 3.1 do)

If you only need a single element then in C++03 you can do:

```
PrintNow(std::vector<int>(1,20));
```

If you need more than one element then I don't think there's any one line solution. You could do this:

```
{ // introduce scope to limit array lifetime
    int arr[] = {20,1,2,3};
    PrintNow(std::vector<int>(arr,arr+sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));
}
```

Or you could write a varargs function that takes a list of ints and returns a vector. Unless you use this a lot though I don't know that it's worth it.

Comment: The `{20}` syntax is supported in at least GCC 4.4.5.

Comment: In C++03, you could use [`boost::list_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of) for a one-line solution with no extra named variables.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `std::vector::push_back()` returns `void`, not that you can't pass a temporary to the function.

Comment: `void vector::push_back ( const T& x )`

Answer (score 6):

Yes we can.

```
points.push_back(vector<int>{1, 2, 3, ....});
```

I'm initialising the vector like array and not giving it a name. Pretty simple for single or multiple elements.

Answer (score 5):

The error is generated because the return type of `std::vector::push_back` function is `void`:

```
void push_back ( const T& x );
```

Try the following:

```
PrintNow(std::vector<int>(1, 20));
```

The code above uses one of the available constructors of `std::vector` class:

```
explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

Answer (score 4):

If all the elements are of the same value, you have one constructor that fits your needs:

```
PrintNow(std::vector<int>(1,20));
```